# An example of a 2 generated nonlinear solvabe group

Tags: group-theory

can you give me an example of a 2 generated nonlinear solvable group?
All metabelian groups are linear due to Magnus. An example of a 3 generated nonlinear solvable group is $(\mathbb{Z} \wr \mathbb{Z})\wr \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I don't think I can answer your question, but out of curiosity, what does $\wr$ denote?

Comment: @tomasz , that is the usual notation for the (regular) wreath product

Comment: You mean "all finitely generated metabelian". Actually, "linear" means here "linear over some commutative ring", or probably "over some finite product of fields". The metabelian group $C_6\wr\mathbf{Z}$ is not linear over any field, and also not over any finite product of fields of characteristic zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are even non-residually finite 2-generated solvable groups (of class 3). See Denis Osin's answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30653/hnn-embedding-theorem-for-amenable-groups .