# Let $G$ be a group of order $2014$. Prove that $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $19$ and $G$ is solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

Let $G$ be a group of order $2014$. Prove that $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $19$ and $G$ is solvable.

---

The first part directly follows from the Sylow Theorems, if you write $2014 = 2 \cdot 19 \cdot 53$.

But I really don't know how to prove that it is solvable. How to prove that?

Comment: So it has a normal subgroup $P$ of order $19$. You just need to prove that $P$ and $G/P$ are both solvable, which is easy.

Comment: *NB:* "prove" and "proof" are different words.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623422/can-only-find-2-of-the-4-groups-of-order-2014?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the related links: there are exactly $4$ different groups of order $2014$, which are obviously solvable, as (semidirect) product of solvable (even abelian) groups. For the last claim see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726266/proof-for-semidirect-product-of-solvable-groups-is-solvable).

Answer (score 0):

If $S$ is the Sylow $19$-subgroup then $S$ is normal and cyclic, $|G/S|=2*53$. $G/S$ has unique cyclic Sylow $53$-subgroup $T/S$ of index $2$, so $G$ has a sequence $1<S<T<G$ of normal subgroups with Abelian factors. Hence $G$ is solvable of class at most $3$. In fact the class is $2$ or $1$ because $T$ is a direct product of two groups of orders $19, 53$, hence cyclic.

Comment: What do you mean by class here?

Comment: @DerekHolt Solvable groups of class $k$ or soluble groups of derived length $k$ or разрешимые группы класса $k$, if you prefer.

Comment: For example https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229505/finitely-presented-subgroup-and-free-solvable-group-of-class-3

Comment: or: http://math.caltech.edu/~jaywill/WeaklyUniversalFGSolvable.pdf or https://web.stevens.edu/algebraic/GTI/Files/2011-11-03-talk-Romankov.pdf
or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185591/an-example-of-a-2-generated-nonlinear-solvabe-group
or 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.6506

or http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~tim.riley/papers/Taming_the_hydra/taming_the_hydra_extended_abstract.pdf